# Load component in a popup window in angular2/4

Tags: angular

how  to load a component in a popup window.

Lets say I have a component called as app.component.ts, in this i have a button 
which is calling window.open("somewindow.html"), in somewindow.html i want to load a component called DataComponent.ts, how do i do this ?

Comment: is `somewindow.html` your website or someone else's ?

Comment: somewindow.html is in my website

Answer (score 0):

somewindow.html would have to be a full angular app.  However, why would you even consider doing this?  Popup windows are generally considered a thing of the past, consider using a modal window instead.

If your project is using bootstrap then you could use the NgbModal https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api

Comment: Thanks I shall  try